# How to change the working directory in iPhone programatlically(FTP)

Tags: ios, ftp, cfstream

I am trying to establish FTP connection with FTP server in iOS (Authentication based).
To maintain the login status I am listing the directory and if the directory listing count is zero then login is unsuccessful.

Now my problem is whenever I log in then the root directory is "romfs" as shown in screen shot in red circle and 
I want the directory access to other directory which is at same level as highlighted in red rectangle. So i directly set the url to this directory with the proper username/ password. like this

```
    ----"ftp://server_ip/ahci02:2/db/"
```

[image]

But it is trying to list \romfs folder 
So my question is how to change the working directory from "romfs" to "ahci02:2" programmatically in iOS.

Thnx in advance.

Pgggyyyyy

Comment: What is the code you used to connect ftp ?

Comment: one which is available at http://ipsw.info/trac/browser/iphone-3.0-cookbook/C13-Networking/15-FTP%20Helper/FTPHelper.m

Comment: try changed one sorry .